# Delete few first zeros in a string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, integer

This is what I have been working on:

Giving input as 2 positive integers (at most, 100 digits).

Compare the two integers.

Note: The 2 integers can contain leading zeros.
(that means you have to remove zeros first)

Because 100 digits is too long, I use a `string` datatype.

But in my program below, it just returns `'='`
I debugged it and figured out that the `for` loop isn't working.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; // I know this is bad but it's just a small program

char compareBigInterger(string str1,string str2)
{
    while (str1[0] != 0) str1.erase(0, 1);
    while (str2[0] != 0) str2.erase(0, 1);

    char answerHold {'='};
    if (str1.size() > str2.size())
    {
        answerHold = '>';
    }
    else if (str1.size() < str2.size())
    {
        answerHold = '<';
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++)
        {
            if (int(str1[i] - 48) < int(str2[i] - 48)) // 48 = '1' - 1
            {
                answerHold = '<';
                break;
            }
            else if (int(str1[i] - 48) > int(str2[i] - 48))
            {
                    answerHold = '>';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return answerHold;
}

int main()
{
    string str1;
    string str2;
    cin >> str1 >> str2;
    cout << char{compareBigInterger(str1, str2)};
}
```

Comment: fwiw, your function could just use [mismatch](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch), or [lexicographical_compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines

```
while (str1[0] != 0) str1.erase(0, 1);
while (str2[0] != 0) str2.erase(0, 1);
```

will erase all characters in the strings because the value `0` is used as the end mark of strings.

To compare with character zero, you should use character literal `'0'` (character surrounded with `''`).
Also the loop should be "loop while the character is zero" to remove zeros.

```
while (str1[0] == '0') str1.erase(0, 1);
while (str2[0] == '0') str2.erase(0, 1);
```